# Async methods Explanation

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Ok so I am new to async, await and Task so I played around a bit and googled but I am not quite sure yet how it works and how it is supposed to be implemented
So let me start by giving my code

```
public class MessageQuery
{
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
}

public class MessageQuery<T> : MessageQuery
{
    private SocketLayer _socketLayer;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public MessageQuery(SocketLayer socketLayer)
    {
        this._socketLayer = socketLayer;
    }

    public Task<T> Execute()
    {
        _wait.Reset();//Set the wait
        var task = new Task<T>(SendAndWait);
        task.Start();
        return task;
    }

    private T SendAndWait()
    {
        _socketLayer.ExecuteQuery(this);
        _wait.WaitOne();
        //Deserialize recieved bytes to T
        return default(T);
    }

}

public class SocketLayer
{
    public MessageQuery<T> BuildTask<T>(/*some parameters*/)
    {
        //Build the message query from all parameters

        return new MessageQuery<T>(this);
    }


    public void ExecuteQuery(MessageQuery query)
    {
        //Using Sockets send Buffer
        //Another Thread will listen and receive buffers, with using SequenceId's it will notify the correct MessageQuery to be completed with the result
    }
}

public class GlobalAccess
{
    readonly SocketLayer _layer = new SocketLayer();
    public Task<List<Client>> LoadedClients { get; set; }
    public Task<List<Client>> GetAllClients()
    {
        if (LoadedClients != null)
        {
            var task = _layer.BuildTask<List<Client>>();
            LoadedClients = task.Execute();
        }
        return LoadedClients;
    }
}


public class SomeForm
{
    readonly GlobalAccess _access = new GlobalAccess();

    //Approach I am not using currently
    async void Button_whateverClickWithAsync(/*parameters*/)
    {
        var clients = await _access.GetAllClients();
        //Do whatever
    }

    //Approach I am using currently
    void Button_whateverClickWithoutAsync(/*parameters*/)
    {
        _access.GetAllClients().ContinueWith(HandleResult);
        //Do whatever
    }

    private void HandleResult(Task<List<Client>> x)
    {
        //Using Dispatcher to Do whatever
    }
}
```

The above code is only a 'simplified' explanation of how I designed my classes, there is more to it than just this but it should give you an Idea.
Now I am currently using this in wpf & Xamarin and it works well but in Xamarin I started to use Task and not Thread because PCL has only Task in, this gave me and Idea to rewrite parts of code using the pattern above (which is partially completed) BUT I do not understand the async/await completely, using the above code which will be the better approach to use, or is there a better approach to take

Comment: Write a simple piece of async code, put it through a decompiler and see what comes out (or just look at this page >> http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/danielgrunwald/archive/2012/04/16/decompiling-async-await.aspx ).Async and await are just "syntactic sugar" - an easy way for you to create "linear" code that is executed in a multi-threaded way.

Comment: I'm not sure I actually understand what your question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Matt `async-await` is much more complicated than "syntactic sugar".

Comment: My question is what is the best approach to async

Comment: @DonaldJansen That's a bit broad. What do you mean by "best approach"?

Comment: @Matt You’ll never understand async-await by checking out what it does under the hood for you. If you want to understand it, you should first understand how it allows you to write code (code that appears “synchronous” again).

Comment: Look at SomeForm in my code above, I've added both approaches that I am currently doing

Comment: @poke no, but the point remains that while async and await are very clever, they are not doing anything that could not already be done with threading primitives. Do you not think it's useful for us to understand what the compiler is doing under the hood?

Comment: @Matt Useful, yes, later maybe to understand the implications. But helpful to grasp the concept? I don’t think so, no. Abstractions exist so that we don’t need to worry about what crazy stuff the compiler or interpreter needs to do to make it work. If we had to understand the internals of every construct we use (just think about loops), then we wouldn’t write code like we do today, if we even got to writing code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the best way to think of `await` is as follows:

First, think of this simple list functions to be executed, one at a time:

```
DoSomething();
SomethingElse();
OneLastThing();
```

Now, when you add await:

```
await DoSomething();
SomethingElse();
OneLastThing();
```

A good way to think about it, is as-if the compiler actually generated this Psuedo-code for you:

```
Start Task() => { DoSomething(), OnCompleted = TaskCompletedCallback };

//Once the task has finished, after an unknown amount of time
//call this sort-of auto-generated callbcak
private void TaskCompletedCallback()
{
    SomethingElse();
    OneLastThing();
}
```

Bear in mind, this isn't *really* what's happening, just a nice way to wrap your head around it.

Comment: This makes sence, so from this I can bassically say that using await is somewhat cleaner, and easier to maintain in the end

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking at using explicit continuation with `ContinueWith` vs using `async-await`.

I definitely prefer the latter, is it leads to much cleaner code. It effectively allows you to run asynchronous code while looking at it like synchronous code, which adds a-lot of clarity to what you're attempting to do:

```
async void Button_whateverClickWithAsync(/*parameters*/)
{
    var clients = await _access.GetAllClients();
    // Here, you execute the rest of your code as if
    // running synchronously.
}

void ButtonClick(/*parameters*/)
{
    _access.GetAllClients().ContinueWith(HandleResult);
    // When does the continuation run? What happens if you want
    // to execute this only if the task fails?
}
```

This does boil down to a coding preference. If you choose to use `async-await`, you should learn about it more and understand what actually happens to a method when it's marked as `async`.

Comment: So what I now understand is not only is await cleaner but actually safer than using ContinueWith(xx)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with "safety", more about readability. If you want to handle exceptions that happened inside a `Task`, you can use `await Task` and wrap that in a `try-catch`, like synchronous code. While with `ContinueWith` you'll have to handle it inside the delegate, which feels less natural.

Answer (score 0):

Await = execution stops at this point and your program does other stuff until the await task finishes.
THEN the execution continues right below the await line.

async void = for events, NO wait.

Task t = blaAsync = INSTANT START (you MAY wait later with t.wait)